# MLAgents Agent isn't getting better at training

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, ml-agent

I've been recently working on a **self-balancing pair of legs** that are supposed to try to keep the character from falling over. Each AgentReset, the legs reset all of its necessary factors such as pos, rot, and vel, and the floor beneath the character changes the rotation randomly by less than 5 degrees. Though, no matter what I seem to do with the number of observations the agent takes in, he still **doesn't really seem to learn from his mistakes**. Now, I'm new to machine-learning so go easy on me! What am I missing? Thank you!

**Some notes**: 
I'm not really sure how RayPerceptionSensorComponent3D works. Maybe someone can put me in the right direction if that might help.

[image: traininng]
[image: agent in inspector image description here]
[image: tensorboard data]

**Agent Script :**

```
using MLAgents;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using MLAgents.Sensor;
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;

public class BalanceAgent : Agent
{
    private BalancingArea area;
    public GameObject floor;
    public GameObject waist;
    public GameObject buttR;
    public GameObject buttL;
    public GameObject thighR;
    public GameObject thighL;
    public GameObject legR;
    public GameObject legL;
    public GameObject footR;
    public GameObject footL;

    public GameObject[] bodyParts = new GameObject[9];
    public HingeJoint[] hingeParts = new HingeJoint[9];
    public JointLimits[] jntLimParts = new JointLimits[9];

    public Vector3[] posStart = new Vector3[9];
    public Vector3[] eulerStart = new Vector3[9];

    public RayPerceptionSensorComponent3D raySensors;

    float rayDist = 0;
    float rayAngle = 0;
    Vector3 rayFloorAngle = new Vector3(0,0,0);
    Vector3 rayPoint = new Vector3(0,0,0);

    int rotAgent = 0;

    public void Start() {
        bodyParts = new GameObject[] { waist, buttR, buttL, thighR, thighL, legR, legL, footR, footL };             //Waist = 0, footL = 8.

        for (int i = 0; i < bodyParts.Length; i++) {
            posStart[i] = bodyParts[i].transform.position;
            eulerStart[i] = bodyParts[i].transform.eulerAngles;
            if (bodyParts[i].GetComponent<HingeJoint>() != null) {
                hingeParts[i] = bodyParts[i].GetComponent<HingeJoint>();
                jntLimParts[i] = hingeParts[i].limits;
            }
        }
    }

    public override void InitializeAgent() {
        base.InitializeAgent();
        area = GetComponentInParent<BalancingArea>();
    }

    public override void AgentReset() {
        floor.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(Random.Range(-5, 5), 0, Random.Range(-5, 5));
        print("Reset! - " + rotAgent);
        for (int i = 0; i < bodyParts.Length; i++) {
            bodyParts[i].transform.position = posStart[i];
            bodyParts[i].transform.eulerAngles = eulerStart[i];
            if (bodyParts[i].GetComponent<HingeJoint>() != null) {
                jntLimParts[i].max = 1;
                jntLimParts[i].min = -1;
            }
            bodyParts[i].GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = Vector3.zero;
            bodyParts[i].GetComponent<Rigidbody>().angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;
        }
    }

    public override void AgentAction(float[] vectorAction) {

        float buttRDir = 0;
        int buttRVec = (int)vectorAction[0];
        switch (buttRVec) {
            case 1:
                buttRDir = 0;
                break;
            case 2:
                buttRDir = .2f;
                break;
            case 3:
                buttRDir = -.2f;
                break;
        }
        jntLimParts[1].max += buttRDir;
        jntLimParts[1].min = jntLimParts[1].max - 1;
        hingeParts[1].limits = jntLimParts[1];

        float buttLDir = 0;
        int buttLVec = (int)vectorAction[1];
        switch (buttLVec) {
            case 1:
                buttLDir = 0;
                break;
            case 2:
                buttLDir = .2f;
                break;
            case 3:
                buttLDir = -.2f;
                break;
        }
        jntLimParts[2].max += buttLDir;
        jntLimParts[2].min = jntLimParts[2].max - 1;
        hingeParts[2].limits = jntLimParts[2];

        float thighRDir = 0;
        int thighRVec = (int)vectorAction[2];
        switch (thighRVec) {
            case 1:
                thighRDir = 0;
                break;
            case 2:
                thighRDir = .2f;
                break;
            case 3:
                thighRDir = -.2f;
                break;
        }
        jntLimParts[3].max += thighRDir;
        jntLimParts[3].min = jntLimParts[3].max - 1;
        hingeParts[3].limits = jntLimParts[3];

        float thighLDir = 0;
        int thighLVec = (int)vectorAction[3];
        switch (thighLVec) {
            case 1:
                thighLDir = 0;
                break;
            case 2:
                thighLDir = .2f;
                break;
            case 3:
                thighLDir = -.2f;
                break;
        }
        jntLimParts[4].max += thighLDir;
        jntLimParts[4].min = jntLimParts[4].max - 1;
        hingeParts[4].limits = jntLimParts[4];

        float legRDir = 0;
        int legRVec = (int)vectorAction[4];
        switch (legRVec) {
            case 1:
                legRDir = 0;
                break;
            case 2:
                legRDir = .2f;
                break;
            case 3:
                legRDir = -.2f;
                break;
        }
        jntLimParts[5].max += legRDir;
        jntLimParts[5].min = jntLimParts[5].max - 1;
        hingeParts[5].limits = jntLimParts[5];

        float legLDir = 0;
        int legLVec = (int)vectorAction[5];
        switch (legLVec) {
            case 1:
                legLDir = 0;
                break;
            case 2:
                legLDir = .2f;
                break;
            case 3:
                legLDir = -.2f;
                break;
        }
        jntLimParts[6].max += legLDir;
        jntLimParts[6].min = jntLimParts[6].max - 1;
        hingeParts[6].limits = jntLimParts[6];

        float footRDir = 0;
        int footRVec = (int)vectorAction[6];
        switch (footRVec) {
            case 1:
                footRDir = 0;
                break;
            case 2:
                footRDir = .2f;
                break;
            case 3:
                footRDir = -.2f;
                break;
        }
        jntLimParts[7].max += footRDir;
        jntLimParts[7].min = jntLimParts[7].max - 1;
        hingeParts[7].limits = jntLimParts[7];

        float footLDir = 0;
        int footLVec = (int)vectorAction[7];
        switch (footLVec) {
            case 1:
                footLDir = 0;
                break;
            case 2:
                footLDir = .2f;
                break;
            case 3:
                footLDir = -.2f;
                break;
        }
        jntLimParts[8].max += footLDir;
        jntLimParts[8].min = jntLimParts[8].max - 1;
        hingeParts[8].limits = jntLimParts[8];

        float waistDir = 0;
        int waistVec = (int)vectorAction[8];
        switch (footLVec) {
            case 1:
                waistDir = 0;
                break;
            case 2:
                waistDir = .2f;
                break;
            case 3:
                waistDir = -.2f;
                break;
        }
       // waist.transform.Rotate(0, waistDir, 0);

        //buttR = vectorAction[0]; //Right or none
        //if (buttR == 2) buttR = -1f; //Left

        if (waist.transform.position.y > -1.4f) {
            AddReward(.02f);
        }
        else {
            AddReward(-.03f);
        }

        if (waist.transform.position.y <= -3) {
            Done();
            print("He fell too far...");
        }

        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray r;
        if (Physics.Raycast(waist.transform.position, -waist.transform.up, out hit)) {
            rayDist = hit.distance;
            rayPoint = hit.point;
            rayAngle = Vector3.Angle(waist.transform.position, hit.normal);
            rayFloorAngle = hit.collider.transform.eulerAngles;
        }


    }

    public override void CollectObservations() {

        for(int i = 0; i < bodyParts.Length; i++) {
            AddVectorObs(bodyParts[i].transform.position);
            AddVectorObs(bodyParts[i].transform.eulerAngles);
            AddVectorObs(bodyParts[i].GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity);
            AddVectorObs(bodyParts[i].GetComponent<Rigidbody>().angularVelocity);
            AddVectorObs(jntLimParts[i].max);
            AddVectorObs(jntLimParts[i].min);
            AddVectorObs(raySensors);
            AddVectorObs(rayDist);
            AddVectorObs(rayPoint);
            AddVectorObs(rayAngle);
            AddVectorObs(rayFloorAngle);
        }
    }
}
```

**Area Script :**

```
using MLAgents;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class BalancingArea : Area
{
    public List<BalanceAgent> BalanceAgent { get; private set; }
    public BalanceAcademy BalanceAcademy { get; private set; }
    public GameObject area;

    private void Awake() {
        BalanceAgent = transform.GetComponentsInChildren<BalanceAgent>().ToList();              //Grabs all agents in area
        BalanceAcademy = FindObjectOfType<BalanceAcademy>();                //Grabs balance acedemy
    }

    private void Start() {

    }

    public void ResetAgentPosition(BalanceAgent agent) {
        //agent.transform.position = new Vector3(area.transform.position.x, 0, area.transform.position.z);
       // agent.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0,0,0);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

**Academy Script :**

```
using MLAgents;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BalanceAcademy : Academy
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking at the [Crawler example](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents/blob/master/docs/Learning-Environment-Examples.md#crawler) in the ML-Agents github repo. You probably want to use the same observations as Crawler:
"position, rotation, velocity, and angular velocities of each limb plus the acceleration and angular acceleration of the body."

I'd also recommend copying the trainer_config.yaml settings from Crawler so that you have the best starting point for hyperparameters.

As a side note, RayPerceptionSensorComponent3D works somewhat independently and you don't need to add it to the observations with AddVectorObs() because it does that automatically behind the scenes. You also don't need to add any values to the Space Size for RayPerception anymore. That said, you probably don't want to use RayPerception at all for this problem.

Comment: I've been trying to set it up to allow the agent to know when he's leaning using maybe ray casts but I can't find much info on them. I though RayPerception was the way to go but apparantly not. How would I set up a raycast to allow my agent to see how he is, angled to the ground..? Thanks.

Comment: RayPerception, as it is currently implemented, is not built for what you're trying to use it for. You would have to modify a fair bit of ML-Agents code to support multiple RayPerceptionSensorComponents on child objects of the agent. It's worth noting that RayPerception is kind of like a cheap form of vision. Even humans can't balance well with only (super advanced) vision, we need a functioning vestibular system. Similarly, robots need gyroscopes and accelerometers. I think you've chosen the hardest way to do this, haha! 

Answer (score 0):

I think it is hard for people to quickly follow your code. There are a few main questions for reinforcement learning (rf):

- what kind of model to you use to store your learnings? Popular are q-tables, but also deep neuronal network using q-learning
- what is your reward function and do you use any kind of punishment?

What helps me is to check what updates are made when something is successful and when a negative reward will be applied. In this context also check what does this update mean for your model. Does it also reward the steps before that made it become a success?

It is important that the model can reach the goal step by step. For example a good reward for this example would be a combination of time-passed and an indicator of a perfect balance.

I hope it helps to Target you in the right direction.

By the way, reinforcement learning is very challenging compared to the building blocks it builds upon like just supervised learning approaches. It also helps to check them out. I can really recommend fastai courses that are free and the best I've ever seen for the most important areas of machine learning.

Comment: For the first question, unfortunately, I don't follow. Again, I'm awfully new to all of this! All I can say, is I'm using Anaconda to run my ML-Agent training. It's just saving  to a '.nn' file.

Though for the 2nd question, in the Agent script near the bottom, I check to see if the waist is at a certain height. If it is, +reward, else -reward.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using transform.positions to setrewards and end episode when this waist touches the ground(like check for collisions between waist and ground) (or) check if the waist and other parts are at same transform.position and setrewards accordingly.

*And also could you put up the link of your unity project file. I would like to see what you've done there.*

Answer (score 0):

Throwing this out as a possibility but did you forget to put `--train` in your `mlagents-learn` command? This has got me a few times.

Answer (score 0):

For a space size of 207 for observations, I would strongly recommend letting your agent train for way longer than just 10k steps.  5 million or more might be reasonable.  Really, just try training for longer, like overnight for example to see if anything different happens.  It also helps a lot to have multiple copies of the ML robot training at once to train much faster.  Try making multiple copies of the environment.  (I would advise putting the robot and the plane in an empty gameObject and then duplicating that 8-16 times)  You don't have to do anything special, just duplicate and run as normal and the other copies will also train.